# How to Inject IHostingEnvironment in My Own Class

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have below code to create a log file.

```
public class LoggingService
{
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment env;

    public LoggingService(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
            this.env = env;
    }

    public void WriteLog(string strLog)
    {
            //Some code is Here
    }
}
```

Following Access the Class in Controller Function

```
LoggingService log =  new LoggingService();
log.WriteLog("Inside GetUserbyCredential function");
```

When I am trying to create an instance from a controller class to pass some value to the function. At the time I am getting the following error

> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'env' of 'LoggingService.LoggingService(IHostingEnvironment)'

How to create the instance for this.

Comment: How are you using the `LoggingService` class? Can you add the code where LoggingService is used i.e. created/injected into a controller, and also your `startup.cs` (especially where you register your `LoggingService` class).

Comment: i am not did anything in startup.cs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is in the following line:

```
LoggingService log =  new LoggingService();
```

When you are creating Instance of `LoggingService` class you are not passing the `IHostingEnvironment` to its constructor and that's why its getting null.

To overcome this problem try as follows:

```
public interface ILoggingService
{
   void WriteLog(string strLog);
}

public class LoggingService : ILoggingService
{

    private readonly IHostingEnvironment env;

    public LoggingService(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        this.env = env;
    }
    public void WriteLog(string strLog)
    {

        //Some code is Here
    }
}
```

Then in your controller:

```
public class YourController : Controller
{
     private readonly ILoggingService _loggingService;
     public YourController(ILoggingService loggingService)
     {
         _loggingService = loggingService;
     }

     public IActionResult YourMethod()
     {
        _loggingService.WriteLog("Inside GetUserbyCredential function");
     }
}
```

Finally in the `ConfigureServices` method of the `Startup` class as follows:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddScoped<ILoggingService, LoggingService>();
}
```

Comment: i am getting this error in Startup class .The name 'env' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Okay! Try again removing the `services.AddSingleton<IHostingEnvironment>(env);` and let me know if it works!

Comment: You don't need to create an interface. You can register the class directly. Also, `.NET Core` registers `IHostingEnvironment` for you so that code is unnecessary

Comment: @SATHEESHP Great to see if has been worked for you! Welcome!

Comment: @SimplyGed Your approach may works but using interface is always the best choice while you are creating services and accessing the services through interface.

Comment: I didn't say it was better - I just said you didn't need to do it :-)

Comment: Yeh! Okay.Thank you!

Comment: I have a doubt. I have a helper class. The controller calls  the helper class and pass some value to its function. In this how can i use ILoggingService. Because the hepler class has  parameterized constructor.

Comment: Yes! You can! You can simply get the Instance of `ILoggingService` by using `GetService()` method of the `HttpContext` or or `IServiceProvider`. If you really need this, just put the requirement and I am answering this thoroughly.

Comment: Yes i need your help.My need is Controller class function calls the HRegisteration class and its function with some parameter at that time the writelog function from LoggingService need to call. How can i do it.

Comment: i am not did any thing after refreshing the page the green mark is automatically removed.

Comment: Okay! Can you give me remote access so that I see your HRRegistration class  code!

Answer (score 1):

DependencyInjection in `.NET Core` requires you to register your classes and their dependencies so it can create/retrieve any dependencies before creating an instance of your class.

Based on your comments I am assuming you have not registered your `LoggingService` with the services collection and that you are trying to create an instance in your controller.

First thing, you need to register your `LoggingService` with the `IServiceCollection` in startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<LoggingService>();

    services.AddMvc();
}
```

This tells the DI service that when a class asks for a `LoggingService` in it's constructor, it has to create an instance of this class. Behind the scenes `.NET Core` has already registered the `IHostingEnvironment` interface with the DI service so we don't need to worry about that. When the DI service has to create an instance of our `LoggingService` it will automatically inject the `IHostingEnvironment` dependency.

Now we need to inject the class into our controller:

```
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    private readonly LoggingService _loggingService;

    public ValuesController(LoggingService loggingService)
    {
        _loggingService = loggingService;
    }

    ...
}
```

When `.NET Core` creates an instance of our `ValuesController` it will see if it knows how to create an instance of `LoggingService` - which is does because we told it about our class in `startup.cs`.

One thing to remember about Dependency Injection you almost always **NEVER** use `new` to create a class. (There are exceptions to this but you should always try to let the DI service create the classes without you needed to use the `new` keyword).

I suggest you spend some time reading the [documentation on Dependency Injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2) so you fully understand how dependency injection works in `ASP.NET Core` and the different scopes available.